# Input selection in Python using IF statements

Tags: python, if-statement

Im trying to create code that prints a game's difficulty level based on what the "diffChoice" value is using IF statements. However, I can't get the "gameDiff" value to correctly represent what the "diffChoice" was. Any help/feedback is appreciated.

```
diffChoice = 'm'

if diffChoice == 'e' or '1':
    gameDiff = 'EASY'
if diffChoice == 'm' or '2':
    gameDiff = 'MEDIUM'
if diffChoice == 'h' or '3':
    gameDiff = 'HARD'

print(gameDiff)
```

Answer (score 0):

In all of your Boolean conditions, the second expression after the `or` is truthy, so `x or y` will always yield `True`.

Consider:

```
if "1":
    print("I'll print!")

if "2":
    print("So will !")

if "":
    print("I won't print; the empty string (an empty sequence of characters) is treated as False.")

if []:
    print("I won't print: the empty list is treated as False.")

if False or 1:
    print("I WILL print: False or 1 is treated as False or True.")
```

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). In particular:

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a **bool**() method that returns False or a **len**() method that returns zero, when called with the object.

What you want is to test `a or b`, so write:

```
if diffChoice == 'e' or diffChoice == '1':
    gameDiff = 'EASY'
```

or, equivalently:

```
if diffChoice in ('e', '1'):
    gameDiff = 'EASY'
```

and so on.